# PrimeFaces Calendar mindate / maxdate format error

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I'm trying to set mindate and maxdate in a Primefaces Calendar control.  I get an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

The code is very simple:

```
<p:calendar value="" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" mindate="01/01/2012" maxdate="05/31/2012" mode="inline"/>
```

I assume the problem is the format used in the strings for the mindate and maxdate attributes, but I can't see what the problem would be, especially as I've explicitly defined the format in the pattern attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the `format` or the `mindate`/`maxdate`.

The problem is actually the `value=""`. I presume you're trying to display blank as the default. The `<p:calendar/>` component being a strictly-typed component will attempt to parse and convert `" "` to a `java.util.Date` object. Obviously that's going to cause it to choke.

You're better off binding the `value` attribute to an uninitialized `Date` field in your backing bean or setting a default value with the `pageDate` attribute, which is not as strongly-typed (takes an `Object`)

Comment: Thanks!  You are absolutely right.  And for a quick-fix for display purposes only, the value attribute can be omitted completely.